# Shape detection in specific area of image open cv python

Tags: python, algorithm, opencv

I am capturing still images of old super 8mm film and want to detect the spindle hole on the left side of the image. At times there are multiple holes in the image. I would like to detect the hole at the centre of the image with opencv using python.

I have played with the standard opencv detect square python script and I can detect the holes. But I am having trouble finding a way to limit the search for the hole in the center of the image.

I would like to be able to detect the center hole and crop the image based on the position of that hole.

Below is the basic script I'm playing with. Any help to where I can start looking to solve this is appreciated.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

'''
Simple "Square Detector" program.
Loads several images sequentially and tries to find squares in each image.
'''

# Python 2/3 compatibility
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
PY3 = sys.version_info[0] == 3

if PY3:
    xrange = range

import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv


def angle_cos(p0, p1, p2):
    d1, d2 = (p0-p1).astype('float'), (p2-p1).astype('float')
    return abs( np.dot(d1, d2) / np.sqrt( np.dot(d1, d1)*np.dot(d2, d2) ) )

def find_squares(img):
    squares = []
    for gray in cv.split(img):
        for thrs in xrange(0, 255, 26):
            if thrs == 0:
                bin = cv.Canny(gray, 0, 50, apertureSize=5)
                bin = cv.dilate(bin, None)
            else:
                _retval, bin = cv.threshold(gray, thrs, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)
            contours, _hierarchy = cv.findContours(bin, cv.RETR_LIST, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
            for cnt in contours:
                cnt_len = cv.arcLength(cnt, True)
                cnt = cv.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.02*cnt_len, True)
                if len(cnt) == 4 and cv.contourArea(cnt) > 1000 and cv.isContourConvex(cnt):
                    cnt = cnt.reshape(-1, 2)
                    max_cos = np.max([angle_cos( cnt[i], cnt[(i+1) % 4], cnt[(i+2) % 4] ) for i in xrange(4)])
                    if max_cos < 0.1:
                        squares.append(cnt)
    return squares

def main():
    from glob import glob
    for fn in glob('/home/trent/Pictures/image0001.jpg'):
        img = cv.imread(fn)
        squares = find_squares(img)
        cv.drawContours( img, squares, -1, (255, 0, 0), 3 )
        cv.imshow('squares', img)
        ch = cv.waitKey()
        if ch == 27:
            break

    print('Done')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(__doc__)
    main()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Hi Tailwind2010, and welcome to Stack Overflow! When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

This is a rough job of finding the center then
using a DIY filtering "return_important_contours" and then using cv2.pointPolygonTest to find the distance from each center. you probably could just cut out the filtering all together.

```
return_contour_nearest_center_function(image):
 rows, cols, ch = image.shape
 middle=(rows/2,cols/2)

 selected_contours=return_important_contours(image,50,0.5,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
 min_distance=1000000
 min_distace_tag=0
 for i in range(0,selected_contours.__len__()):
    dist = abs(cv2.pointPolygonTest(selected_contours[i], (cols/2, rows/2), True))
  #  print("each distance"+ str(dist) )
    if dist<min_distance:
        min_distance=dist
        min_distace_tag=i

 if selected_contours.__len__()==0:
    return ;
 return selected_contours[min_distace_tag];
```